# Offering a smiley button on text input in Android

Tags: android, html

When I compose an SMS message in Android, instead of the Enter button there's a smiley face, which I can click to add `:)`

Can this functionality be added in HTML (5?)? I was hoping for something like :

```
<input type="text" data-type="SMS" />
```

Such that the android knows that it should offer smiley options

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think that's possible. Try searching on Google's android documentation, but I doubt you'll find anything.